# Excel VBA copy range to a new sheet after 1,048,576 rows

Tags: vba, excel

So I wrote a fairly simple Macro in VBA that updates a set of variables, then copying and pasting the updated values into a new sheet. The problem is that the volume is getting a bit overwhelming now, thus reaching the 1,048,576 row limit in Excel, causing the code to crash.

I would like to update it so that whenever the rows limitation is reached, the script begins copying the cells to a new sheet (say, "FinalFile2","FinalFile3", etc) until it's fully executed.

```
Sub KW()
'
' Exact KWs
'
Dim i, j, LastRow As Long
Dim relativePath As String

i = 2
j = 2

'LastRowValue'
Sheets("Output").Select
LastRow = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

'Clean final output'
  Sheets("FinalFile").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select

'Set Variables in Variables sheet'

Do

'Var 1'
    Sheets("Names").Select
    Range("A" & i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Variables").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

'Var 2'
    Sheets("Names").Select
    Range("B" & i).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Variables").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

 'Var 3'
    Sheets("Names").Select
    Range("C" & i).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Variables").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

 'Var 4'
    Sheets("Names").Select
    Range("D" & i).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Variables").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


 'Var 5'
    Sheets("Names").Select
    Range("E" & i).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Variables").Select
    Range("E2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


  'Var 6'
    Sheets("Names").Select
    Range("F" & i).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Variables").Select
    Range("F2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

   'Var 7'
    Sheets("Names").Select
    Range("G" & i).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Variables").Select
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


    'Var 8'
    Sheets("Names").Select
    Range("H" & i).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Variables").Select
    Range("H2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False



     'Var 9'
    Sheets("Names").Select
    Range("I" & i).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Variables").Select
    Range("I2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False



     'Var 10'
    Sheets("Names").Select
    Range("J" & i).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Variables").Select
    Range("J2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False



     'Var 11'
    Sheets("Names").Select
    Range("K" & i).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Variables").Select
    Range("K2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


'Copy and Paste'

    Sheets("Output").Select
    Range("A2:AP2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("FinalFile").Select
    Range("A" & j).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

'update counters'

i = i + 1
j = j + LastRow

'end of loop condition'

Sheets("Names").Select

Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))



End Sub
```

Comment: How long does this run until the sheet is full? It sounds like you need to use  a variable sheet and create a new one one `j` reaches 1,048,576  and reset `j`. Also you should definitely remove the selections http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Comment: Also aren't you overwriting the values in the variables sheet? It all get's pasted to row 2.

Comment: The longer I look at this the more confused I am. You Copy a lot of different lines of the `"Names"` sheet to the same row of the `"Variables"` sheet and the same line from the `"Output"` sheet to `"FinalFile"` over and over always skipping `lastRow` lines

Answer (score 2):

Here are some tips how to improve your code. I am not going into the issues I mentioned in my comment on the original question but just concentrate on specific parts of the code:

1. Remove `Selection`s. The general pattern is instead of

   ```
   something.Select
   Selection.Dosomenthing
   ```

   you use

   ```
   something.Dosomething
   ```

   In your case:

   ```
   Sheets("Names").Select
   Range("A" & i).Select
   Selection.Copy
   Sheets("Variables").Select
   Range("A2").Select
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
   :=False, Transpose:=False
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   Sheets("Names").Range("A" & i).Copy
   Sheets("Variables").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
   :=False, Transpose:=False
   ```
2. Use variables to reference your sheets like this:

   ```
   Dim nameSheet as Worksheet
   Dim varSheet as Worksheet
   Dim finalSheet as Worksheet

   Set nameSheet = Sheets("Names")
   Set varSheet = Sheets("Variables")
   Set finalSheet = Sheets("FinalFile")
   ```

   Now you can use

   ```
   finalSheet.Range(...).Pastespecial ...
   ```

   and use `Set finalSheet = Sheets("FinalFile2")` once you run out of space
3. Don't copy cells next to each other one by one. You are copying cell `Ai` to `A2` then `Bi` to `B2`. Just copy the range `Ai:Ki` to `A2:K2` (although I don't see the point of this)
4. Don't use `Copy` if you don't need to. Instead of

   ```
   someRange.Copy
   someOtherRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   ```

   you can use

   ```
   someOtherRange.Value = someRange.Value
   ```

   (make sure the sizes are the same)
5. Disable `Screenupdating` using `Application.Screenupdating = False` (set it to `True` after you're done) when you're doing a lot of insertions. It can speed up a macro a lot.
6. As to your actual question, do as Tom suggests, add

   ```
   If j > 1048576 Then
       j = 2
       Set finalSheet = Sheets("FinalFile2") 'maybe create the new sheet at this point
   End If
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
j = j + lastRow
If j = 1048576 Then j = 2
```

BUT you should *definitely* clean up this code. `.selections` are a really slow way to do stuff like this. Look into [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/us-en/library/office/ff838238.aspx) and try to avoid `.Copy` & `.Paste`. Just set your target cells to the values of your source with an `=`. This also saves a lot of time.

Edit: And definitely take a look at the link posted by @arcadeprecinct